# How to set maximum width and height in fullscreen mode

Tags: html, css, unity-webgl

I am working on a Unity WebGL application and I would like to know if it was possible to set a maximum Width & Height for the game canvas.

I tried to do it in the TemplateData style.css

```
#gameContainer canvas:fullscreen 
{
    width: 1920px !important;
    height: 1080px !important;
    margin: auto !important;
}
```

But it's not working.

When I check the computed tab in the Chrome dev tools, the width is set to 2560 and the height to 1440 which is my screen resolution.
My css code is applied since I can see it when I unfold the "width" and "height" entries in the computed tab.

Is it possible to bypass the webkit fullscreen height and width ?

Comment: can't you use vh and vw? and not worry about height and width ever :)

Comment: if you want it to be full screen (fit screen resolution with no scrolling). just edit width and heigth to make: `width: 100vw`,`height: 100vh`

Comment: No it's not the issue here.
We're trying to put a maximum canvas size because Unity WebGL use the browser window resolution as the game resolution. If you're using an IMac with a retina screen (5K), the game will run in 5K when in fullscreen.

We need to set a flat maximum value to avoid that.